# How to append rows from one Dataframe to another having different column structure

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I have two excel files, the first one has 34 columns and the second one has 19 columns, the first one has all these 19 columns but if I add some empty column I can get the structure of the first file. I want to append rows from 2nd file to the first file

I added empty columns to get the same structure as the first one but when I tried to merge both data frames I got:
     ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned (maybe because of those empty columns doesn't have a name )

```
merged = pd.read_excel(r'D:\Incident in detail.xlsx')
resolved = pd.read_excel(r'D:\Data set\Resolved Incident.xlsx')
for i in range(13,26):                                                     
    resolved.insert(i,"","",allow_duplicates=True)                         
resolved.insert(33,"","", allow_duplicates=True)
resolved_planning = resolved[resolved['Priority'] == '5 - Planning']
merged.append(resolved_planning, ignore_index = True, sort = False)
merged.to_excel(r'D:\test.xlsx', index = False)
```

I also tried using itertuples() but didn't get anything on how to append a list as a row into a data frame.

Edit1:

There is a library dplyr in R in which there is a method bind_rows() which can append rows by column name [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585517/adding-rows-to-a-dataframe-based-on-column-names-and-add-na-to-empty-columns)

Comment: `pd.concat([df1,df2],sort=False)`?

Comment: Same error - ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is efficient or not but this is what I did:

```
new_res = pd.DataFrame(data = resolved_planning.values, columns = merged.columns)
new_merged=merged.append(new_res, ignore_index = True, sort = False)
```

I made a new data frame (new_res) with the first data frame's header and second data frame's (resolved_planning) values and then appending both data frames.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to use the `concat` function in pandas (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html). 
As an example

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(data=1*np.ones((5,34)))
df2=pd.DataFrame(data=2*np.ones((6,19)))
pd.concat([df1,df2],axis='rows').reset_index().drop('index', axis=1)
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6   ...   27   28   29   30   31   32   33
0   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  ...  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  ...  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  ...  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
3   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  ...  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
4   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  ...  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
5   2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6   2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7   2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8   2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9   2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
10  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

You can then relabel the column names as appropriate.

Comment: getting the same error - ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned